# Перенаправление трафика на локальный домен

Tags: ssl, https, iptables, squid

Стоит задача запретить весь http и https трафик  некоторым пользователям, с возможностью перенаправления их на страницу-заглушку в локальной сети, при обращении их в инет...

Iptables справляется, но у пользователей браузеры ругаются на самоподписанный сертификат.
squid не умеет работать с https, а в сборку с https у меня руки кривые, или тыкните в актуальный мануал.
Либо подскажете, пожалуйста, порядок дейтсвий, или что делать, чтобы браузеры не ругались на сертификаты
Спасибо.
сервер ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Очень хотелось бы использовать прозрачный прокси. У каждого прописывать не всегда получится, а пользователи-обычные юзеры...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще будет весь HTTP/HTTPS трафик разрешить только на сквиде и запретить на шлюзе. Т.е. ты прописываешь руками или используя proxy.pac прокси на всех браузерах, остальные проги пусть ходят, как ходили (если так устоит) и на сквиде трафиком полностью управляешь.

Есть ещё более жёсткий вариант, на шлюзе инет вообще не раздаёшь, а даёшь на нём доступ только на прокси-сервер, там рулишь абсолютно всем.